# htacces rewrite split part if last folder

Tags: .htaccess, url, split

I would like to rewrite with htacces:

original url:

```
www.site.com/images/abcdefg/imagename.jpg
or www.site.com/images/100x100/abcdefg/imagename.jpg

to

www.site.com/images/**fg/de**/abcdefg.jpg 
or www.site.com/images/100x100/**fg/de**/abcdefg.jpg
```

(get last 2 chars from last folder as first folder and the two chars before that as 2nd subfolder)

beside that if the rewirten url doesn't exist redirect to
images/converter.php

like

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /converter.php/$1
```

I cannot get the firt part to work, please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)([^/]*)([^/]{2})([^/]{2})/([^/.]+)\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$ /$1$4/$3/$2$3$4.$6 [L]
```